# Is it correct to say "a lot of kinds of fruits"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Some non-native English speakers use words in a very strange way.

One said "**a lot of kinds of fruits**".

It sounds pretty strange to me.

Do we have to say "**many kinds of ....**" all the times?

Comment: Though unusual, "a lot of kinds of fruits"  is correct grammatically. You usually say many kinds of....

Comment: Does the noun following *many kinds of* have to be in the plural form? :)

Comment: **a lot of** sounds perfectly normal to this US English native speaker.  Did you look up the phrase "a lot"?

Answer (score 1):

> a lot of kinds of fruit

Is incorrect. You can say:

> Many kinds of fruit
>
> different kinds of fruit
>
> many different kinds of fruit
>
> many types of fruit

Or

> a lot of fruit

Answer (score 0):

In British English, it's common to say 'all sorts of fruit' instead. Even when you don't literally mean 'all' but 'many'.

"...kinds of" is rarely used in my experience.